# jQuery loading items via ajax and while remove it getting notification from all previous deletion as well

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, sticky

I have a div like this

```
<section class="item_container">

<article class="item">
    <h2>Page Title</h2>
    <p><a class="delete_page" href="http://www.abc.com/delete/1/">delete</a></p>
</article>

<article class="item">
    <h2>Second Page Title</h2>
    <p><a class="delete_page" href="http://www.abc.com/delete/2/">delete</a></p>
</article>

</section>
```

And i am using this code to remove/delete `items` from `item_container`

```
$('a.delete_page').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('footer#ajax_footer').html('')
    $('footer#ajax_footer').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 500);

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var parent_div = $(this).parents("div").parent("article");
    var title = $(this).parents("div").parent("article").find('h2').html();

    $('footer#ajax_footer').html('<h2>Are you sure you want to delete <u>'+ title +'</u> Page</h2><p>'+ url +'</p><p><a href="#" class="delete_this_page">Yes, Please Delete It</a></p>');

    $('a.delete_this_page').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        parent_div.remove();
        $('footer#ajax_footer').html('').slideUp();
        $.sticky('<b>Page Deleted</b><p><u>'+ title +'</u> Page has been successfully deleted.</p>');
    });

});
```

All the contents are loaded via Ajax and there are few more div in each `article` and there are 30+ articles.

The problem is i am using Sticky plugin to display notification after every item is deleted and it's working fine, Everything is working fine, But after i delete an Article, The sticky notification of previous deletion is displayed as well.

Like, After i delete an item, i see 1 sticky notification, After i delete second item i see 2 sticky notifications (1 of this and 1 of previous) i only want to see 1, And For every item i delete it display all the previous sticky notifications + 1.

Hope i made it clear enough, Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that every time you click on a `a.delete_page` element you're setting up a **new** click event handler using `.live()`, so for each subsequent click you get one more event handler that gets run.

The whole point of `.live()` - though, as a side note, it's deprecated; consider using `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` (prior to 1.7) - is that it handles events triggered by dynamically added elements. Call this:

```
$('a.delete_this_page').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        parent_div.remove();
        $('footer#ajax_footer').html('').slideUp();
        $.sticky('<b>Page Deleted</b><p><u>'+ title +'</u> Page has been successfully deleted.</p>');
    });
```

outside of your other callback function (in your `$(document).ready()`), and find another way to identify `parent_div`. Or, bind the click event to that specific link directly inside the callback handler.

Comment: Hello, Changing
$('a.delete_this_page').live() to
$('a.delete_this_page').on() solves all the problem, but if i change $('a.delete_page').live() to $('a.delete_page').on() as well, it causes problem for dynamically loaded items.

Comment: @Roccos There are two uses of `.on()`. `$('selector').on('event', function() {...});` binds the event to **existing** elements when the code is run, so doesn't recognise elements that are added later. You need to use `$('.item_container').on('click', 'a.delete_page', function() {...});` so that it sets up event delegation and will trigger from dynamically added elements.

Comment: Even after doing this the issue remains same, But my previous issue/problem is solved and thanks for that. I am looking into these right now.